# Java Logging shows unwanted date and method while logging into a file

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am maintaining a log file generated by the java program (`java.util.logging`), which is working fine but it puts one extra line of info every time when it logs to the file.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
    FileHandler fh;  

    try {  

        // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
        fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/ABC/MyLogFile.log");  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

        // the following statement is used to log any messages  
        logger.info("Welcome, App is opened at : " + new Date());  

    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    logger.info("It's running now");  
    logger.info("Took Following URLs from the user:"); 
}
```

output is like:

```
Feb 05, 2015 3:19:54 PM webservertracker.ImprovedImplementation main
INFO: Welcome, App is opened at : Thu Feb 05 15:19:54 IST 2015
Feb 05, 2015 3:20:49 PM webservertracker.LauncherUI$ButtonClickListener actionPerformed
INFO: It's running now
Feb 05, 2015 3:20:49 PM webservertracker.LauncherUI$ButtonClickListener actionPerformed
INFO: Took following URLS from the User:
Feb 05, 2015 3:20:49 PM webservertracker.LauncherUI$ButtonClickListener actionPerformed
```

Readability is less here.

I need something like this :

```
INFO: Welcome, App is opened at : Thu Feb 05 15:19:54 IST 2015
INFO: It's running now
INFO: Took following URLS from the User:
```

How to achieve this. Do I need to customized it, if so then How?

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using a properties file

You need to use the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` [key](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7152819) in `logging.properties`:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$s: %5$s%n
```

This yields a result like this one:

```
INFO: This is an informational message
```

#### Using a command line parameter

Another option is specifying this in a command line parameter:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%4$s: %5$s%n"
```

#### Setting it up programmatically

If you are setting up the logger programmatically, you have to make your own subclass of `java.util.logging.Formatter`, because you the format field is a private variable in `SimpleFormatter`. For example, in your case, your formatter can be implemented as:

```
class MyFormatter extends Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(record.getLevel() + ": ");
        builder.append(formatMessage(record));
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        // pre-Java7: builder.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'));
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

then you can use `MyFormatter` to format you log messages. You can set up your console logging using this Java code:

```
ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
logger.addHandler(handler);
Formatter formatter = new MyFormatter();  
handler.setFormatter(formatter);
```

Comment: can you please explain with above format what i need actually.

Comment: i need only log info what i will put using 

           obj.logger("My formatted string");

Comment: java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%4$s: %5$s%n" is saying that format is a private variable for SimpleFormatter class.

Comment: Because it is. See my changes in the answer

Comment: Formatter class can not be extend as it seems a final class.

Comment: java.util.logging.Formatter is an abstract class, it is the superclass of SimpleFormatter, so it is not final

Comment: but it gives error: cannot inherit from final Formatter.

Comment: Are you sure it is `java.util.logging.Formatter`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html

Comment: yeah I made it correct, earlier it was 'java.util.Formatter' actually. Now it's ok. but how to use it [convert the logger.info("-----"); method] ?

Comment: Thanks, it working now. But the '\n' is not working as it logs in the same line only. it should log in next line only.

Comment: I always forget, the line separator is `\r\n` in Windows, updated that part of the Formatter